# Framework for Integration Test in a Microservice

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, karate

I am working on a Service API ( Spring, Java ) which calls an external service to fetch some data.

We have a Karate test for some of the endpoints that runs on buildkite ( CI/CD process ) in an isolated environment `buildkite-my-service:8080`.

From this `buildkite-my-service:8080`, I cannot connect to external Service to validate my Karate tests. Although Karate tests run fine on my `localhost:8080` as I can connect to this external Service.

What would be the best way/ library/ framework to have an Integration test in such a scenario?

Comment: You probably need a fake external service - otherwise you might find it difficult to get the conditions to have repeatable tests - that lets you exercise as much of what you want before needing to setup state for a repeatable "actual" service test.

Comment: dev of karate here - skip to 33:30 of this video for some ideas: https://youtu.be/yu3uupBZyxc?t=2013